# When I upload the build to iTunes Connect - the icon doesn't appear. It appears on diawi link for the ipa I uploaded to diawi.

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I uploaded a build and it successfully uploaded but the icon didn't appear so I uploaded another version and the icon didn't appear again even when the status of build changed from processing to inactive. It shows icon for a previous build I uploaded but I don't want o submit that for review as it has bugs. What should I do? The app was updated from Xcode 5.1 to xCode 6.2 - not sure as this is the cause of the problem as some builds show icon and some don't.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you looking for the icon? In test flight or in My Apps in iTunes connect? The icon does not transfer to iTunes connect. You must drag in a 1024 x 1024 version of your icon into the field of iTunes connect. This is what shows up on the App Store. The icon that you add into your app with image.xcassets only shows up when the app is run on a phone.

I might have not understood you correctly so let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Same for me, but the icon showed up when I checked on the following day. Seems to be some sort of delay in iTunes Connect when we upload the build. No actions are necessary.